# SQlite: how to find mutually exclusive pairs?

Tags: sqlite

There is a table `Likes` with fields `ID1` `ID2` which contain mutually exclusive pairs like

```
1689    1709
```

and

```
1709    1689
```

I want to find them. I tried it by concatenation and it didn't work.

```
select L.ID1,L.ID2
from Likes L
where (L.ID1||L.ID2) = (L.ID2||L.ID1);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by mutually exclusive pair here?

Comment: 1689 1709
1709 1689

Comment: The reason your attempt doesn't work is that the `WHERE` clause is evaluated for single rows at a time... in your case, two of the tests will be `16891709 = 17091689` and `17091689 = 16891709`, neither of which is true.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to join the table to itself:

```
SELECT L1.ID1, L1.ID2 FROM sometable L1
JOIN sometable L2 ON L1.ID1=L2.ID2 AND L1.ID2=L2.ID1
```

This will show you the ID pairs that have the opposite pair in the table. This will also show the pair other way around also (1,2 as well as 2,1), if you don’t want that you can add `WHERE L1.ID1<L1.ID2` for example.

You could also use `EXISTS` clause but I think this is simpler.